# Execute separate spring batch job if original job failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have one main spring batch job that has multiple steps. If that job for some reason fails, I need to call another job to update a table in my database with the failure results.

How can I configure my batch flow to do this?

I created a JobExecution like so, but I don't know how to call a new job from either of the if/else statements:

```
@Bean 
    public JobExecutionListener dataListener() {
        JobCompletionNotificationListener dataNotificationListener = new JobCompletionNotificationListener(new JdbcTemplate(dataDataSource));
        dataNotificationListener.afterJob(jobExecution());
        return dataNotificationListener;
    }


@Bean
public JobExecution jobExecution() {

        JobExecution jobExecution = new JobExecution(jobExecution());

        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {

            // If job completed successfully, update current job log to success


        } else if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED) {

            // If job failed, update current job log to failure

        }

        return jobExecution;
    }
```

Comment: you could use that when ItemWriter throws exception and end batch process with a exit code. when the exit code arrives save the data in db with your stuff..

Comment: I would say we use Listener afterJob(). We can check status of job in afterJob method() so perform our logic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener class to your job which implements `JobExecutionListener` interface and call your logic in `public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution)` method after checking condition `jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED`.